# Modificar atributos de uma label com nome dinamico

Tags: c#, string, label

Exemplo
Fiz isso pois estou criando Controles e nomes dinamicamente, pois bem. o problema esta quando preciso usar ou chamar esses valores.

Se eu quiser mudar o valor do controle seu texto ou valor ,algo do gênero.
Queria saber se há uma forma de faze-lo.

Meu código:

```
public int Playes = 0;

private void Criacao()
        {
             Playes += 1;

    string HP0 = "Lab" + Playes.ToString();  //Sempre que criar o controlle Adiciona 1 no int Playes, dai o nome fica algo como : "Lab1"

    Label L1 = new Label(); //Criação do label.

    L1.Name = HP0; // definir nome da label.
    L1.AutoSize = true; //Define o tamanho automaticamente.
        }
```

Dai simplificando, gostaria de saber se há como mudar a valor dos controles, 
diferentes exemplo `Lab1.text = "teste"` ou `Lab2.text = "teste2";`, pois como estou mudando o nome em processo não sei como chama-lo. 
(Perdão se esta mal explicado, sou leigo ainda.)

Comment: Posta o código que faz a geração dos controles dinamicamente porque senão fica difícil adaptar a lógica que você usou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após criar os seus controlos:

```
// Exemplo de criação de 3 labels
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    Label label = new Label()
    {
        Name = "Lbl" + i.ToString(),
        Text = $"Label " + i.ToString()
    };

    this.Controls.Add(label);
}
```

Basta obtê-los a partir do nome e modificar as propriedades que precisar (neste caso apenas o `Text`):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    var label = this.Controls["Lbl" + i.ToString()] as Label;

    if (label != null)
        label.Text = string.Format(@"Label {0} (modified!)", i);
}
```

Comment: Olá @Kuro. Não se esqueça de dar um UP nas respostas que lhe foram úteis :). [Porque é importante votar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 4):

Tente utilizar dessa maneira:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int contador = 1;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void AddNewLabel()
    {
        //Define posição top
        var top = contador * 25;

        //Novo label
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Top = top;
        lbl.Left = 10;
        lbl.Text = "Lab " + this.contador.ToString();
        lbl.Name = "Lab" + contador;
        //Adiciona no Form
        this.Controls.Add(lbl);

        //Incrementa Contador
        contador = contador + 1;
    }

    public void ChangeLabel()
    {
        foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
        {
            if (control is Label)
            {
                if (control.Name == "NOME DO LABEL CRIADO")
                {
                    //Remove o label
                    this.Controls.Remove(control);

                    //Adiciona o label novamente
                    control.Text = "TEXTO A SER ALTERADO";
                    this.Controls.Add(control);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void AdcionarLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewLabel();
    }

    private void TrocarTxtLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeLabel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sim mas minha pergunta é como eu modifico o label criado depois exemplo Lab1.text = "ola"; não quero criar 5 label com o mesmo nome entende? , quero modificar um por 1 depois.

Comment: Desculpe, não havia entendido. Corrigi o código adicionando a função ChangeLabel responsável pela alteração do texto em tempo de execução.